# RavenDB assigning already used Id to Document

Tags: ravendb

I have an excel file that contains a list of UserAccounts.  I also havea method to import those UserAccounts and save them into RavenDB.  In the excel file I store the Id of the UserAccount Object (useraccounts/55).  RavenDB is not assigning the value, I am assigning it.  My import is working great.

However,

Later on, I try to save a new UserAccount through the admin panel using the following method:

```
       [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(UserAccountViewModel input)
            {
               // Validation omitted             

                    var model = new UserAccount()
                    {
                        Email = input.Email,
                        FirstName = input.FirstName,
                        LastName = input.LastName,
                        Phone = input.Phone,
                        Username = input.Username,
                        AuthorizeNetCustomerProfileId = customer.ProfileID,
                        Password = input.Password,

                    };

                    Raven.Store(model);
                    Raven.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
             }
```

When I call

```
Raven.Store(model)
```

It assigns an Id to the new UserAccount object but it starts at 1.  So the first time I try to do this it assigns UserAccounts/1 to my new UserAccount.   The issue is that UserAccounts/1 already exists from my import so when I call save changes I am getting an etag exception.

When I run the method again it assigns UserAccounts/2 and so on? Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to have a string Id property in your UserAccount class, and assign it a value of "UserAccounts/". That trailing slash is going to ask RavenDB to assign it an ID using an identity-like process, instead of HiLo. Its somewhat slower, but it'll work.

The better way of solving this is by changing the HiLo documents on the server, making them start with the first available range, but thats messier.

Comment: So the first suggestion didn't work.  So I went in and adjusted the HiLo document on the server per your second suggestion and that fixed it.  I think that after the import I will just create the HiLo document in code and so it knows where to begin.

Comment: The first should have worked - you need to do that before you call Store on the object, and I think you can actually pass it as a parameter to Store itself